# getPrettyFormat() not working with some SVG images in Google Apps Script

Tags: xml, parsing, svg, format, drive

I need some help finding out why some SVG images when formatted with `getPrettyFormat()` look as expected and some others seemed not getting the pretty format. First I extract the files from Drive and then parse them using XmlService.parse(), the code is the same for every image:

```
function xmlRead(){    

    var id = "some id of an svg image stored in Drive";
    var rawXml = DriveApp.getFileById(id).getBlob().getDataAsString()
                 var xml = XmlService.parse(rawXml);
    var output = XmlService.getPrettyFormat().format(xml);

    DriveApp.createFile('image'+'.svg', output, MimeType.SVG); 
    Logger.log(output);
}
```

For example, [this svg image](https://www.google.com.mx/search?q=svg+image&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiSu_OJ5oHdAhWmyoMKHUnWDgAQ_AUICigB&biw=1236&bih=557#imgrc=9gzWD9XTri9a_M:) doesn't get pretty formatted.

But [this one](https://www.google.com.mx/search?q=svg+image&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiSu_OJ5oHdAhWmyoMKHUnWDgAQ_AUICigB&biw=1236&bih=557#imgrc=LxVkEzxl4WKXAM:) gets pretty formatted.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, it has to do with the xml:space attribute and it's value "preserve" inside SVG images. When the attribute is omitted, getPrettyFormat() works well. More info of this attribute [here](http://www.xmlplease.com/xml/xmlspace/) .